# Funny looking learning curve

Tags: machine-learning, python, xgboost

I am training an XGBoost for binary classification. I am getting a very odd-looking learning curve. Any idea what is going on and how I might fix this? Thanks[image]

Comment: That is funny. What is the y-axis score? Accuracy?

Comment: y is accuracy; x is the number of training examples

Comment: Maybe you have some garbage in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is that you are working on a dataset for which accuracy is inadequate, for example, in an imbalanced target dataset.

So It may happen just by chance that you have few positive cases in the specific set of 90,000 samples.

So you have a few options:

1. Change the metric for PR-AUC
2. Redifine your code to stratify at every step:

   ```
    from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
    from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

    cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)


    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
    model, X, y, cv=cv, train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 10),     scoring='roc_auc', shuffle=True
   ```

   )